# Which x-order tree traversal (depth first search) is being used here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[This leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/submissions/) is solved quickly using some depth-first traversal since it involves subsets:

```
class Solution(object):
    def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
        """
        :type candidates: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        results = []

        if candidates == None or len(candidates) == 0:
            return results

        candidates = sorted(candidates)

        combination = []
        self.recurse(results, combination, candidates, target, 0)

        return results

    def recurse(self, results, combination, candidates, target, startIndex):
        '''
        walk the tree, looking for a combination of candidates that sum to target
        '''
        print("combination is : " + str(combination))
        if target == 0:
            # must add a copy of the list, not the list itself
            results.append(combination[:])
            return;

        for i in range(startIndex, len(candidates)):
            if candidates[i] > target:
                break

            combination.append(candidates[i])
            self.recurse(results, combination, candidates, target - candidates[i], i)
            combination.remove(combination[len(combination) - 1])

s = Solution()
results = s.combinationSum([2,6,3,7], 7)
print(results)
assert results == [[2, 2, 3], [7]]
```

...However, I cannot tell exactly which type of traversal is used here. I recognize in-order traversal when I see the use of "nodes" and "left"/"right" properties like this:

```
def inorder(node):
  if node == None: return
  inorder(node.left)
  do_something_with_node(node)
  inorder(node.right)
```

...but the references to nodes and left/right children are not explicit in this solution. "Nodes" are subsets of the `candidates` list in this case, but is this in-order traversal? Or pre/post-order?

*Update: I printed the `combination` at the top of `recurse` and got this:

```
combination is : []
combination is : [2]
combination is : [2, 2]
combination is : [2, 2, 2]
combination is : [2, 2, 3]
combination is : [2, 3]
combination is : [3]
combination is : [3, 3]
combination is : [6]
combination is : [7]
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe this is a recursive tree traversal as opposed to a simple recursion.

Comment: @coldspeed - a java version of this problem explained via tree traversal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irFtGMLbf-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pre-order traversal. This means the order it visits nodes in is (root, children). The `recurse` function is essentially a glorified version of:

```
def depth_first_search(state):

    if state is solution:
        results.append(state)
    for next_state in next_possible_states:
        if next_state is valid:
            depth_first_search(next_state)
```

First it visits the current node and checks if it's a solution. Then it moves on to the children. Pre-order traversal.

Comment: your pseudo code makes sense. Can you look at the update to my question to see if the printed results match what you're describing?

Comment: Yes they do. You start with the root (`[]`), you then go to the first child of the root, check if it's a solution, you move onto the child of the child. Once you hit `[2, 2, 3]`, you're out of valid children to visit. So you're back to the other child of the root. And this goes on and on and on. All of this is visit parent, then the children.